# Share structures between HLSL and C++

Tags: c++, hlsl

I have a lot of structures and have duplicates in C++ and HLSL code.  What is your advise on how to share structure between HLSL and C++ parts. I think i would need file with typedefs for common types in C++ part and shared header with structures. How have you handled it?

Comment: What did your internet search provide?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews , nothing. Or i don't know how to search for such thing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to share a struct between C++/DirectX and HLSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886497/how-to-share-a-struct-between-c-directx-and-hlsl)